# Facebook Like button push down my web site content by 1 pixel after load

Tags: html, css, facebook

Like button push down my web site content by 1 pixel after load? What causes this?

The website:
http://mihalko.eu/

http://screencast.com/t/0YaQlZPmtRv

Comment: maybe the like button also add a container to add a comment (i know some like button do that) but due to some of your style its not showing just making the empty container. ?

Comment: It looks like it's going up and down, if you click multiple times does it really change?

Comment: @Lil'Monkey, I dont know, I generated this Like button via official FB Like button creator, and I checked to show only button with counter /no comment option/

Comment: does not happen in IE9. which browser are u using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `iframe` height is causing that. Give a `height` to `#facebook_like` and that should prevent it from moving changing when the `iframe` height changes. You can even add it a `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem! Thanks!